# Mysql / PHP / json_encode boolean string conversion

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a mysql query lets say:

`SELECT cca_id AS id, cca_title AS text,IF((SELECT count(*) from crm_categories WHERE cca_id_prev = id),'TRUE','FALSE') AS children FROM crm_categories WHERE...`

now I get an array back with true / false as a string

If I use json_encode the result is like `{"id":"false"}`

But I need true/false without quotes - the problem is if i use true false in the mysql query as a boolean it returns 0/1 - but I don't want that either...

Of course I can run a `str_replace` to the json string - but i think there are alternatives isn't it?

Comment: how are you going to end up using the boolean? in JavaScript?

Comment: i use jstree and jstree demands a notation like {"children":false}

Comment: If you use php you can do like: $result[]['children'] = $data['children']? true: false; What do you think?

Comment: yes i think i can do that - but i've to iterate through the array - in this case i can use str_replace too which seems not the best solution here - i don't want to iterate through the given array just because of that

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, you *are* selecting from the database as string. So that's what gets encoded. Use SQL `true`/`false` boolean values, which in PHP become `0`/`1`, and cast them to PHP booleans before JSON encoding them:

```
$data['id'] = (bool)$data['id']; // 0/1 -> PHP false/true

echo json_encode($data); // {'id':true}
```

Comment: yeah in this case i've to iterate through the array too - but i guess you r right - this seems the best solution for now

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem :

I used PHP for convert value `gettype`, example with **POST** :

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
        settype($_POST[$k], gettype($v));
}}
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that the data returned from mysql is a string, not a boolean. If you know that it is always going to be either 'true' or 'false', you can compare it with a string literal to get the correct type:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$boolval = ($row['boolval'] === 'true');
```

And then later, when it is `json_encoded()` it will be represented as a primitive boolean, instead of a string.